# Electric guitar with Roland Hp107e

Tags: electric-guitar

Is it possible to play an electric guitar through the back panel input jack on the Roland Hp107e?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Remember this: electric guitars are usually very weak electrical signals (so-called "low level line signal"), and usually need to be boosted (with a "pre-amp" for example) so enough sound is generated to the output jack. Test the guitar without any boost and check if something can be heard. Maybe, or maybe turning the knobs up. If that's the case, you'll want something to use as a pre-amp. Like a pedal, an amplifier or monitor, something like those.

Now, about the Roland, I have seen that some of those keyboards (can't remember the brand) that working in a strange logic, just as follows: the logic is that the sound gets generated ONLY by pressing the piano key, and if there's something connected to the input jack, it creates a sound in that precise tone of the piano key pressed.

Tried it?
Kind regards.

Comment: A link to these special keyboards would be nice. The function sounds really unusual.

Comment: Are you looking for a link of the Roland keyboard or one that works sounding only when the note is pressed and together with the input instrument?

Comment: The latter, I think that function is rather unusual

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. As far as I can tell, the digital piano has input jacks that allow it to be used as a powered speaker for any line level source.

The output from electric guitar on the other hand is far from line level. The voltage is roughly in the right range but can't provide enough current for a normal line input, and without equalization the sound is very dark. A guitar preamplifier, amp modeler or many multi effects have suitable input and handles the EQ and other sound processing. With one of these devices the guitar can be used with a home stereo, PA system or indeed this piano. But there is nothing in the digital piano that would make it especially suitable for guitar.